# Why am I getting a 404?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, http-status-code-404

I am trying to link my google maps to a html page. It is returning

> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2017 22:24:05] "GET /luca.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Any ideas why?

```js
new google.maps.event.addListener(marker12, "click", function () {
  window.open('t3xm.html');  });
}
```

My html path is `http:// 127.0.0.1:5000/ t3xm.html`

[layout of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HI0b.png)

Comment: Because it doesn't exist in that directory. There is a lot of information missing here.

Comment: Apologies, the wrong photo was added. It is in the directory under templates. Its now up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you are referencing wrong path.

`window.open('t3xm.html')` will look for this file in document root of your server.

Probably it's set to `/static`. To solve this you might want to create a route to serve this file for you.

PS. You need to give us more information about problem. Are you using any library? What server do you use etc...